# Lower an electron energy level by pressure

Tags: electrons, orbitals

When an atom is in extreme pressure like a little before it's Schwartzchilds radius, can the electrons in higher energy levels physically be compressed into lower energy levels?.

Comment: This question might get more traction on physics.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because chemistry is not ordinarily concerned with black holes.

Comment: Electrons do not need to be pressed into lower energy level. If there is a vacancy in that level, the electron will go there by itself, and quite willingly. If there is no vacancy, nothing can be done. Pressure, however great, can't overrule the Pauli exclusion principle.